# How best to extract xml tags in java without using xml-specific tools?

Tags: java

The specification requires to validate a simplified xml syntax, primarily the order of tags with a stack. While the use of standard classes is allowed, I don't think xml-specific tools would be. Should I use string.split or tokenizer or something else? The goal is to extract text within <>, push if no leading /, else try to pop.

Comment: Why would XML-specific tools not be "allowed"? The JDK itself ships with a few.

Comment: I think because the goal is to provide one's own implementation.

Comment: Can you achieve clarity on the goals and requirements first?

Comment: I think I have. Yes, homework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have the right idea, use the stack.

You can write a simple parser using a stack to keep track of tags. Worst case you can use regular expressions.

Comment: Should I avoid regular expressions here? Do you mean using them with or instead of the stack? Which splitting method for extracting tag names should I use?

Comment: definitely use a stack; for simple tags you can do string matching (substring from index of < and index of >)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind parsing simple, well-formed tags is pretty straight-forward.  You have a stack, you split the text (tokenizer sounds good), compare each token to a list of tags, and every time you encounter a tag, you push it.  Keep reading until you get to another tag, make sure it's the same one on the top of the stack, pop it, and do whatever you want to do with the content.